# What flags can I add or are added when loading the kernel to enhance Sandy/Ivy Bridge performance

Tags: 12.04, performance, intel

Are there any flags in Ubuntu 12.04 that I can add or are added already that when loading the kernel it enhances the performance of Sandy or Ivy Bridge hardware?

In my case my motherboard is the DZ68DB: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dz68db.html

Comment: What is your motherboard brand/model, and are you using the onboard HD2000/HD3000 GPU?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Although I have an Ivy Bridge processor (i-7 3630 QM) and personally find this question interesting it is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL and kernels have changed a great deal in the 5+ years since this question was posted. As such I'm compelled to VTC as `not reproducible`.